# Where to find wsgen tool?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, wsgen

Where to find the wsgen tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the wsgen tool used to generate Java stubs from a WSDL file, it is included with JDK6 and located in the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven, https://jax-ws-commons.dev.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/ is excellent.